# Is there an easy to use extensible layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to create a layout that extends to the whole screen if there is space.

Actually, I want to display information next to its title.

I found something that works, but I feel it is more a hack than a real solution.

```
<TableLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/resort_infos"
    android:stretchColumns="0">
    <TableRow android:background="#0b66ad" android:padding="3dip">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/openSlopesKmTitle"
            android:text="@string/slopes_km" android:textColor="#EEE" />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/slopes" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="right"
            android:textColor="#EEE" android:paddingRight="15dip" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

This allows me to extend the first column and let enough space for the second one. Is it the right way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do it is using `RelativeLayout`, this way:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/slopes"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:textColor="#EEE"
        android:paddingRight="15dip" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/openSlopesKmTitle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/slopes"
        android:text="@string/slopes_km"
        android:textColor="#EEE"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```